# Which objects do I need to explicitly release when calling Windows API functions from C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, pointers, marshalling

I am using the following code to call a winapi function from C#.

```
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr PathFindFileName(string p);

    IntPtr pStr = PathFindFileName("Test");
    string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pStr)
```

I would like to know how to distinguish between objects that require releasing once done, and objects that do not.

For example: In the code above, do I need to release pStr ?

Or does the garbage collector do it automatically ?

In case I do need to release, how is it done ?

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: This code is bad: `pStr` is a dangling pointer.

Comment: @CoryNelson that is what the person is asking about.

Comment: @MichaelEngstler - for future note, the question title you used isn't very good; a better one for this would be "Which objects do I need to explicitly release when calling Windows API functions from C#?" or something along that line; [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), under "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". (The question itself *is* good, at least it seems that way to just-woke-up me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to know how to handle the memory for interop is to read the documentation.

In this case the documentation is a bit weak and doesn't say explicitly what is going on. What is going on is that the pointer that function returns points to some point in the buffer that you supplied. This means that the buffer that you pass to the function must be valid after the function returns for you to be able to read from it. And as you have written the p/invoke using automatic marshalling of a `string` parameter, the buffer that is passed to the unmanaged function is out of your control. Your code might appear to work some of the time, but it is definitely broken and could fail with rather nasty runtime errors.

You need to marshal the string manually so that you can control the lifetime of the buffer that you supply.

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr PathFindFileName(IntPtr pPath);

....

string path = ...;
IntPtr pPath = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(path);
try
{
    IntPtr pFileName = PathFindFileName(pPath);
    string fileName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pFileName);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pPath);
}
```

That's the answer to the question that you asked. However, the best solution to your problem is to avoid interop and use the built in .net library functionality for path manipulation.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the reason you need to do it this way versus the way in the original question is that the memory pointed at by pStr in the original can potentially be corrupted prior to Marshal.PtrToStringAuto returning the correct string.  It may look like it is working correctly now but there's a good chance that you'll end up with strange bugs in the future due to corrupted file names.

Comment: @Dave76 I think I did mention that already in the second para

Comment: You described the problem but weren't specific about the side effect.  I figure the OP might not understand the ramification of using the original code since it may appear to be working correctly during development.  And I agree with you that using the .NET Path class is the better way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I liked your solution for allocating and releasing the string by myself, without needing to take the risk of the string being freed before I use it. That saying, I will probably try to mimic PathFindFileName using .Net libraries.

Answer (score 2):

This particular WinAPI function is a tricky one. The returning pointer points to the input buffer. It means that it is not allocated and **should not be released by you**. In addition you are lucky if the code works, because you need the input buffer to be live until `PtrToStringAuto` copies its contents to a managed string.

Do you really need to call this particular WinAPI function? You can find the same function in `System.IO.Path` class of .NET Framework library.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx

You probably want `Path.GetFileName`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I noticed Path.GetFileName but it works slightly different from PathFindFileName so its not good enough for me. How would you suggest to call this api ? Would it be better if I (somehow) allocate the original string and release it myself ? (In order to avoid the race condition)

Comment: You originally asked whether to release the memory. The answer is simple: Don't release it. When you ask how to use the function, I still think you should rather combine more functions of Path class to mimic the behaviour you want, than to call WinAPI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What you say is false. The pointer returned by this function points to the middle of a memory block allocated elsewhere. You should NEVER use this pointer to release memory block. Becacuse it is not a memory block. Only the memory block used as input parameter must be released here, and that's done by p/invoke automatically. The problem here is that the system can possibly release the memory before the user calls PtrToStringAuto.

Comment: @Al OK. I don't mean that you need to release the pointer returned. But you do need to release the buffer, because you have to allocate the buffer. But your answer intimates that. I should have read it more closely. Sorry. I will tidy up my spurious comments.

Comment: In other words there are two pointers here, but only one of them need to be released/freed, because the other one points to the same memory block. (And in addition it does not point to the start of that block.)

Comment: @Al Yes. My answer demonstrates how to call this API safely but surely it should be avoided and the .net library used instead. As you said.